# What does »Gettofäuste verteilen« mean?

Tags: german-to-english, expression

The two below paragraphs come from the article in *Der Spiegel* called “[Jugendliche in Frankreichs Banlieues. Kurz vor dem Knall.](http://www.spiegel.de/lebenundlernen/schule/frankreich-jugendliche-in-den-banlieues-wo-polizisten-scheitern-a-1173524.html)” My question refers to the expression *Gettofäuste verteilen* used in the first sentence of the second paragraph. What does it mean? Literal translation of *to distribute ghetto fists* does not make sense to me.

> Hadama Traoré, 32, will Bewohner und Beamte wieder versöhnen. Er ist in Aulnay-sous-bois geboren und war früher Rapproduzent. Im Januar gründete er die Bewegung "La révolution est en marche". "Ich will, dass meine kleinen Töchter irgendwann wie Französinnen respektiert werden", sagt Traoré. Seine Eltern stammen aus Mali.
>
> Er bewegt sich wie ein Star in seinem Viertel Rose-des-Vents: klopft Schultern, **verteilt Gettofäuste**. "Hey, Soldat, alles klar? Die Revolution ist im Gange!", begrüßt er einen Vater mit Kind an der Hand. Autos hupen ihm zu, Menschen versammeln sich um ihn, wenn er über den Wochenmarkt läuft.

Comment: Das ist sicher so eine Faust-Begrüssung, die die Leute im Vorort einander geben.

Comment: Genau: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faustgru%C3%9F

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mit **[Gettofaust](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/32003-Ghettofaust)** (alternative Schreibweise *Ghettofaust*) ist umgangssprachlich der [Faustgruß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faustgru%C3%9F) gemeint, der als fist bump seine Wurzeln in den US-amerikanischen Ghettos haben dürfte.

[image]
<sup>[Source:Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Fist_bump_animated_illustration.gif)</sup>